# GDPR and SharePoint User Lookups

Tags: sharepoint, lookup

(not only) because of GDPR when an employee leaves the company all his personal data should be removed. Files should be removed for that user and the user itself from the Active Directory.

But even if the User is removed from the AD all "Created By", "Modified By" and other Userfields still may contain the name from that employee even for documents that belong to others and should not be deleted.

How to solve this issue without breaking SharePoint/Applications that depend on (any) valid person information on those lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear out a user's personal information (name, email, etc) from the user profile service so that SharePoint only references their (hopefully anonymized) user ID.

If necessary, you can also use PowerShell and the client-side object model (CSOM) to override any leftover info (captured in site collection user information lists) with something like "[Redacted]".

Refer to Microsoft's GDPR compliance documentation for SharePoint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/gdpr-for-sharepoint-server#user-profile-data).

> Follow these basic steps to remove a user’s personal information from their SharePoint Server user profile:
>
> 1. Remove the user information from any external systems that feed into the SharePoint Server user profile. If you are using directory synchronization, the user must be removed from the on-premises Active Directory environment.
> 2. Run a profile synchronization on SharePoint Server.
> 3. Delete the profile from SharePoint Server. Once this is done, SharePoint Server will fully remove the profile from the User Profile Database in 30 days. The user’s profile page and personal site will be deleted.
>
> After deleting a user’s profile, some limited information (such as user ID) may still be recorded in site collections that the user has visited. If you choose to delete this data from a given site collection, this can be done using CSOM. A sample script is provided below:
>
> ```
>  $username = "<admin@company.sharepoint.com>"
>  $password = "password"
>  $url = "<https://site.sharepoint.com>"
>  $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
>
>  # the path here may need to change if you used e.g. C:Lib.
>  Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16ISAPIMicrosoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
>  Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16ISAPIMicrosoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
>
>  # connect/authenticate to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.
>  $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
>  $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
>  $clientContext.Credentials = $credentials
>  if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
>  {
>      Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$Url'" -ForegroundColor Green
>  }
>
>  # Get user
>  $user = $clientContext.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName("i:0#.f|membership|user@company.sharepoint.com")
>
>  # Redact user
>  $user.Email = "Redacted"
>  $user.Title = "Redacted"
>  $user.Update()
>  $clientContext.Load($user)
>  $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
>
>  # Get users
>  $users = $clientContext.Web.SiteUsers
>
>  # Remove user from site
>  $users.RemoveById($user.Id)
>  $clientContext.Load($users)
>  $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
> ```